# limit of a radical

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

[image]

I want to find the limit of infinite nested radical, but I don't know how to express this in mathematica. I used Fold[] but I couldn't make it exactly like this.

Comment: `3,9,10,11` whats the pattern?

Comment: Related: [Limit of Nested Radical](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87359/limit-of-nested-radical-sqrt1-sqrt222-sqrt333)

Comment: 3 is just an independent number added to it. The pattern is 1,2,3 and 9,10,11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little different formulation, I wonder if its valid to choose any particular value for the last value where we choose to truncate the expression:

```
val[n_Integer, r_] := Module[{f},
  f[n] = r;
  f[i_] := Sqrt[(7 + i) +  i f[i + 1]];
  f[2]]
val[6, r]
```

[image]

so we can see this converges to the same value  with large `n` regardless of the terminal value `r`.

```
Show[Table[
  ListPlot[Table[{n, Sqrt[3 + val[n, r]]}, {n, 2, 20}], 
   Joined -> True] ,
  {r, {0, 1, 2, 5, 20, 100, 1000}}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I don't think qualifies as proof of convergence, but its pretty convincing.

Comment: I cant get the same plot as yours

Comment: Sqrt[3 + val[n, r, 2]] What does this part mean

Comment: oops, the 2 doesnt belong, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Will this function work?

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_, y_, n_ /; (j = n; True)] := Sqrt[x + f[y, n - 1]] ;
f[y_, n_] := Sqrt[y + (j - n + 1) f[y + 1, n - 1]];
f[y_, 0] := Sqrt[y];

f[3, 9, 5]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works! Do you know how to take limit of it by any chance? (as it approaches infinity?)

Comment: @chanzuixia Try this: `i = 1; While[f[3., 9., i] != f[3., 9., i + 1], i++]; f[3., 9., i]`

Answer (score 2):

The quantity of interest will be written as

$$x=\sqrt{a(1)+3}$$

Here $a(1)$ is to be replaced using this recursion relation (deduced from the easily recognizable pattern)

$$a(n)=n \sqrt{a(n+1)+n+8}$$

The special feature is here that works upward, i.e. $a(1)$ is given in terms of $a(2)$, etc.

In order to evaluate the recursion we need to fix a value of $a(n)$ at some "upstream" index $n = nmax$ to $0$.

The code is short

```
x[nmax_] := Module[{a, n},
  a[n_] := a[n] = n Sqrt[8 + n + a[n + 1]];
  a[nmax] = 0; Sqrt[3 + a[1]]]
```

Example

```
x[5]
```

[image]

The limit can be calculated approximately numerically

```
Table[x[n] // N, {n, 10, 15}]

(* Out[9]= {2.72861, 2.72877, 2.72885, 2.72888, 2.7289, 2.7289} *)
```