# Limit of an infinite nested radical?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, education, system-limitations

Is it possible to compute the limit of this infinite nested radical in Mathematica:

```
Limit[Sqrt[n+Sqrt[n+Sqrt[n+Sqrt[n+...]]]], n->0]
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87359/8822 if not duplicate.

Comment: `Solve[y == Sqrt[x + y], y]` might be useful.

Comment: @J.M. I know the answer, but I was hoping to see if it's possible to evaluate this type of limit symbolically

Comment: @mattiav27 I don't think it's a duplicate - it's not solvable by partial sums

Comment: In that case, I don't think *Mathematica* has built-in support for continued radicals.